# Firestore in Angular Project.DOCS are not showing when getting collection Docs,If those DOCs do not have any fields in it,But Subcollection inside it

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

Iam Using Firestore in Angular Project.DOCS are not showing when trying to get collection Docs,If those DOCs do not have any fileds in it,But a Subcollection inside it.

I have 290 Docs inside a Collection named 'my-maincollection' which all have subcollection named 'my-subcollection'. But out of that only 30 Docs in 'my-maincollection' have some fields in it .

When I try to list all docs,Only those 30 with proprties inside is listed and Others are ignored.
I want to know the workaround,Since I want to take all the subcollection docs

```
      const collectionRef = firebase.firestore().collection('my-maincollection');

      const querySnapshot = await collectionRef.get();
      console.log(querySnapshot.docs.length) //is only 30 .Its supposed to show 260
```

Comment: The document IDs that are shown in italics are not actually documents, but it's just the UI showing you that there are subcollections under that path. And since there are no document, they won't be returned by any document read operation. --- The only solution/workaround is to create the necessary parent documents.

Comment: So there is no way to get the subcollection with no parent fields.If we can write to firestore there must be a way to get that right? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: There don't have to be fields, but the document has to exist in order for you to be able to read it.

Comment: If there are subcollections under a path,then that means there is a document under which all teh subcollections are there right?
My question is how we can retreive the data if the above is the condition.

Comment: No. The presence of a subcollection doesn't necessarily mean the parent document exists. It is perfectly valid to have a subcollection without a parent document. Since that may to the behavior you're seeing, the console displays such document IDs in italics and contains a label explaining the behavior.